# How to create multiple health checks in GCP corresponding to different instances?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

In the following image below I am trying to create a load balancer.

I have added two instances, let say vm1 enabled at port 80 and vm2 at port 86.

In order to do so, I am not able to create an health check for each instances, since GCP is allowing me to create only one.

But in tutorials available online I could see users are able to create multiple health checks. In my case I am not able to create an health check more than once. Since I am new to GCP and struggling to find a solution for this
[image]

I am trying tcp load balancer because it allows me to create custom ports, since I have VMS enabled at ports 80, 85, 86 etc.

I referred [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtLhVvSFi84&list=RDCMUCJS9pqu9BzkAMNTmzNMNhvg&start_radio=1&rv=FtLhVvSFi84&t=178).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single backend can use only one health check, on one port, as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks#hc-port-flags).
If you are serving HTTP traffic, you can use [HTTP(S) Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal) and place your VMs in separate backends. Each backend can use different health check.

As a workaround, you can add a dummy service on VM2, running on port 80 so that the health check can verify if the machine is running.

Feature you mention has been already requested [here](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/153473402). However, there is no ETA when it will be available.

Comment: That corp link is rather useless to non-Googlers. Is there a public facing link also?